# "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" error can't be resolved

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am following the swiftris tutorial here: https://www.bloc.io/tutorials/swiftris-build-your-first-ios-game-with-swift#!/chapters/679

This tutorial was built for xcode 7, but i am using xcode 10. I have an error, Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range, that I cant seem to resolve. Here is my code:

```
class Array2D<T> {
      let columns: Int
      let rows: Int
 // #2
      var array: Array<T?>

      init(columns: Int, rows: Int) {
          self.columns = columns
          self.rows = rows
 // #3
        array = Array<T?>(unsafeUninitializedCapacity:rows * columns, initializingWith: {_,_ in })
      }

 // #4
      subscript(column: Int, row: Int) -> T? {
        get {
            return array[(row * columns) + column]
        }
          set(newValue) {
              array[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
          }
      }
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Oh gosh, this is way too outdated. And your tutorial might actually confuse you... This code you are sharing is typical from Swift 1/2 when there was no native API to handle 2D arrays easily. Now you can create a 2D array natively doing `var grid = [[Object]]()` and access it normally `grid[5][3]`.

Comment: if you initialise with rows = 5 and columns = 5, are you accessing it one-indexed:  (1,1) through to (5,5), or zero-indexed: (i.e. (0,0) to (4,4)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the line at #3 as shown below:

```
     init(columns: Int, rows: Int) {
         self.columns = columns
         self.rows = rows
// #3
         array = Array<T?>(repeating: nil, count: rows * columns)
     }
```

`init(unsafeUninitializedCapacity:initializingWith:)` is not for usual use cases.

---

Generally Xcode 7 (Swift 2) is too....o old in the Swift world and you should better find an up-to-date tutorial.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I also understand what you are saying about xcode 7 being outdated.

Answer (score 0):

In the later versions of Swift there is no need to do this as you can create a 2D array directly through 'an array or arrays' like let matrix = [[Int]].

However it is still a good exercise to code your own to understand how arrays and indexing work.

There are two things that could/should be changed from the example.  Initialises the underlying array with `.init(repeating: count:)` and change the subscripting indexing as it currently doesn't work.

For a 0-indexed array with x rows and y columns, i.e. one ranging from (0,0) to (x-1, y-1)

```
class Array2D<T> {
   let columns: Int
   let rows: Int
   var array: Array<T?>

   init(columns: Int, rows: Int) {
      self.columns = columns
      self.rows = rows
      array = Array<T?>(repeating: nil, count: rows * columns)
   }

   subscript(column: Int, row: Int) -> T? {
      guard row <= rows && column <= columns else {fatalError("invalid position"))
      get {
         return array[(column * columns) + row]
      }
      set(newValue) {
         array[(column * columns) + row] = newValue
      }
   }
}
```

For a 1-indexed array, i.e. (1,1) through to (x,y) you'd need to change the subscripting to:

```
   subscript(column: Int, row: Int) -> T? {
      guard row < rows && column < columns else {fatalError("invalid position"))

      get {
         return array[((column - 1) * columns) + (row - 1)]
      }
      set(newValue) {
         array[((column - 1) * columns) + (row - 1)] = newValue
      }
   }
```